# R merge_element() error with no apparent reason (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

So here is a very short example for the code:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=wt,y=mpg,group=1))+
  geom_point()+geom_line()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_rect(fill = "grey"),
        axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))

Error in `**merge_element()**`:
! Only elements of the same class can be merged
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

This is such an annoying error, and I also tried other solutions in the forum but it really seems like something R folks should take care of. This error is prevented by adding a simple theme_bw() (or alike) argument, but it then cancels the text argument within theme()

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=wt,y=mpg,group=1))+
  geom_point()+geom_line()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_rect(fill = "grey"),
        axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))+
  theme_minimal()
```

This works but doesnt apply the axis.text.

Any suggestions?

I excepted to get a figure with bolded text on the axes, and it never happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `panel.grid` is composed of lines and so the theme element to modify is `element_line()`.

If you want to change the fill, you should be using `panel.background`.

```
mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"), 
          panel.background  = element_rect(fill = "grey"))
```

Result:

[image]

On the other hand if you're trying to change the grid line colour then you should be using `element_line(color = ...)`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"), 
        panel.grid  = element_line(color = "grey"))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great. That was spot on. Thank you